# Laravel - Laracasts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel and I tryed erally hard to figure out where the issue is but can't seems to find it. Thanks in advance to everyone..

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`articles_tag`, CONSTRAINT `articles_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `articles_tag` (`articles_id`, `created_at`, `tag_id`, `updated_at`) values (4, 2015-10-05 09:33:18, 0, 2015-10-05 09:33:18))
```

This is the Tag eloquent model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array();

    //get the articles associated with the given tag
    public function articles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App/Article');
    } 
}
```

This is the Articles eloquent model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Articles extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'published_at',
        'user_id' 
    ];

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public function scopePublished($query){
        $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function scopeUnpublished($query){
        $query->where('published_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    //An article is owned by a user
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    //An article has many tags
    //get the tags associated with the tables
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps(); 
    }

    /*
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = mcrypt($password);
    } //key is to user attributes
    */
}
```

This is my create migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        //we are trying to connect articles and tags
        //really it should we article_tag not articles_tag ;)
        Schema::create('articles_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('articles_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('articles_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tags');
        Schema::drop('articles_id');
    }
}
```

This is is Articles migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Articles extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('published_at');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look on my solution and let me know if it helped.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`article_tag`, CONSTRAINT `article_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `article_tag` (`articles_id`, `created_at`, `tag_id`, `updated_at`) values (9, 2015-10-06 13:40:27, 0, 2015-10-06 13:40:27), (9, 2015-10-06 13:40:27, 1, 2015-10-06 13:40:27))

Comment: tried pretty much everything but no success:(

Answer (score 0):

In migration for table `articles_tag`, try modifying the code for that table to (and make sure you have articles table first)

```
Schema::create('articles_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('articles_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('articles_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`articles_tag`, CONSTRAINT `articles_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `articles_tag` (`articles_id`, `created_at`, `tag_id`, `updated_at`) values (7, 2015-10-05 10:18:28, 0, 2015-10-05 10:18:28))

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate creating and setting constraints like:

```
Schema::create('articles_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('articles_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();            
});

Schema::table('articles_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('articles_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');   
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **article_tag** (both word singular) not **articles_tag** in your migration file, as follow:

```
Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

---

If you still want to use as **articles_tag**, you should specify your pivot table explicitly. You should do as follow in your **Tag** and **Article** models respectively:

In **Tag.php**:

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App/Article', 'articles_tag');
}
```

In **Article.php**:

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'articles_tag')->withTimestamps(); 
}
```

For more info visit [Laravel Docs for Eloquent Many-to-Many Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)